# GridLayout and StackLayout UI Design in Nativescript

Tags: javascript, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm trying to design a login page where I'm having form fields which needs to be displayed with respect to login or registration. following is my code:

```
<FlexboxLayout class="page">
    <StackLayout class="form">
        <Image class="logo" src="~/assets/images/logo.png"></Image>
        <Label class="header" v-show="isLoggingIn" textWrap="true" text="Welcome"></Label>
        <Label class="header" v-show="!isLoggingIn" textWrap="true" text="Register"></Label>
        <label class="subtitle" v-show="isLoggingIn" textWrap="true" text="Already have account? Login with your credentials"></label>
        <label class="subtitle" v-show="!isLoggingIn" textWrap="true" text="Fill the details to register!"></label>

        <GridLayout rows="auto, auto, auto">
            <StackLayout row="0" class="input-field">
                <TextField class="input" hint="Your email registered with us" :isEnabled="!processing"
                       keyboardType="email" autocorrect="false"
                       autocapitalizationType="none" v-model="user.email"
                       returnKeyType="next" @returnPress="focusPassword"></TextField>
                <StackLayout class="hr-light"></StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout row="1" class="input-field">
               <TextField class="input" ref="password" :isEnabled="!processing"
                       hint="Your password" secure="true" v-model="user.password"
                       :returnKeyType="isLoggingIn ? 'done' : 'next'"
                       @returnPress="focusConfirmPassword"></TextField>
               <StackLayout class="hr-light"></StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout row="2" v-show="!isLoggingIn" class="input-field">
                 <TextField class="input" ref="confirmPassword" :isEnabled="!processing"
                        hint="Confirm password" secure="true" v-model="user.password_confirmation"
                        returnKeyType="next" @returnPress="focusFirstName"></TextField>
                  <StackLayout class="hr-light"></StackLayout>
             </StackLayout>

             <StackLayout row="3" v-show="!isLoggingIn" class="input-field">
                  <TextField class="input" ref="firstName" :isEnabled="!processing"
                         hint="First Name" v-model="user.first_name" autocorrect="false"
                         autocapitalizationType="none" returnKeyType="next" @returnPress="focusLastName"></TextField>
                   <StackLayout class="hr-light"></StackLayout>
              </StackLayout>

              <StackLayout row="4" v-show="!isLoggingIn" class="input-field">
                   <TextField class="input" ref="lastName" :isEnabled="!processing"
                          hint="Last Name" v-model="user.last_name" autocorrect="false"
                          autocapitalizationType="none" returnKeyType="next" @returnPress="focusMobile"></TextField>
                    <StackLayout class="hr-light"></StackLayout>
               </StackLayout>

               <StackLayout row="5" v-show="!isLoggingIn" class="input-field">
                    <TextField class="input" ref="mobile" :isEnabled="!processing"
                           hint="Mobile Number" v-model="user.mobile" autocorrect="false"
                           autocapitalizationType="none" returnKeyType="done"></TextField>
                     <StackLayout class="hr-light"></StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>

                <ActivityIndicator rowSpan="6" :busy="processing"></ActivityIndicator>
        </GridLayout>

        <Button :text="isLoggingIn ? 'Log In' : 'Sign Up'" :isEnabled="!processing" @tap="submit" class="btn btn-primary m-t-20"></Button>
        <Label *v-show="isLoggingIn" text="Forgot your password?" class="login-label" @tap="forgotPassword()"></Label>

    </StackLayout>

    <Label class="login-label sign-up-label" @tap="toggleForm">
        <FormattedString>
            <Span :text="isLoggingIn ? 'Don’t have an account? ' : 'Back to Login'"></Span>
            <Span :text="isLoggingIn ? 'Sign up' : ''" class="bold"></Span>
        </FormattedString>
    </Label>
</FlexLayout>
```

I am able to have Login screen perfect

[image]

but whenever I try to have registration fields I get only 3 fields:

[image]

All the fields are not displayed. Help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you originally declared only 3 rows (`rows="auto, auto, auto"`) for the GridLayout. If you assign anything other than `0 to 2` to the `row` attribute on any child element of GridLayout, it will be invalid and never shown.

Also it's not recommended to use GridLayout if you just want the items to be stacked vertically, use StackLayout. Something like,

```
<GridLayout>
    <StackLayout>
        ...
        <StackLayout v-show="!isLoggingIn" class="input-field">
        ...
        </StackLayout>
        ...
    </StackLayout>
    <ActivityIndicator :busy="processing"></ActivityIndicator>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: GridLayout is actually the recommended way for most things. In this case, he wants the activity indicator to be centered in the view, it seems (`rowSpan=6`) which can't be accomplished by a single StackLayout

Comment: I got this when I removed `rows="auto, auto, auto"` and `rows` tag from `StackLayout` image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bO41S.png I think it is not working out that way!

Comment: I did `rows="auto, auto, auto, auto, auto, auto"` all the fields are visible but the buttons are not visible now https://i.stack.imgur.com/NO0Oy.png

Comment: @Bass yes, GridLayout is the most recommend but not for everything. StackLayout should be the choice if you want to stack items like here, one after another.

Comment: @NitishKumar you need a ScrollView so you can scroll down to the buttons